# Angular SSR functionality

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I hope you are doing well. Recently I need to use Angular universal to render my app SSR , but I have faced with some issues that i could not find any solution for and unfortunately i could not find any articles and technical documents on the internet.
I make my problem so simple that based on the solution I extend that for my entire app.
I have one http request get service that i get list of users from external resources. here is my code :

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.userList = res;
    })
  }
```

i just print the name of users in the html. in order to use angular universal feature i install @nguniversal/express-engine package based on Angular document and i run ng run angular-ssr:serve-ssr script to run my app. everything works fine and when i go to network tab i can see that the ssr is working and i can see the result in my document. but here is my problem :
when i deploy my app on the iis microsoft azure and i hit the url to get the result I should wait about 20 seconds to load my page and the request have data till i decorate my html with the result.
what should i do that my ssr works fine like CSR app? do i miss something in my app.
I would be really appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: Do you wish to only render the template on server and run your api call from the client browser?